# GridView with both declarative (Html side) datasource and code-behind datasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview

in ASP.NET 3.5 web page, a GridView control can have both SqlDataSource and code-behind datasource (with a DataTable for example)?
Both datasource are equal (the same stored procedure).

Thanks a lot.

Luis

Comment: Is this a question or a statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible only under one condition.That you set the DataSourceID to nothing of your gridview before re-assigning its datasource to a datatable.Otherwise visual Studio will scream loudly at you in these lines
'***Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'yourGrid'. Remove one definition.***'

```
 yourgrid.DataSourceID=null;
 yourGrid.DataSource=yourDataTable;
```